# Display Kafka messages on web page

Tags: javascript, java, apache-kafka, frontend

I have a Java Spring Application with a Tomcat server that listen on kafka topic. I want to display all messages in a real-time mode on the web page. Therefore, when a kafka messages is arrived in the backend I want to see it on my web page. I don't know a good approach to push kafka message directly to the front-end and display it on web page. Is someone could help my with a solution and some examples that could help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented a system like this in Java for my last employer, albeit not with Spring/Tomcat. It was consuming messages from Kafka and serving them on a web socket to be displayed in the browser. The approach I followed was to use [akka-stream-kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html) and [akka-http](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html#handling-messages) for web-socket support. The benefit of that is both are based on akka-streams which makes it an easy fit for streaming data.
While you can embed akka-http in your spring app running inside tomcat, it may not feel the most natural choice any more as spring framework already has its own support for both kafka and websockets. However, if you're not familiar with either, then jumping on the akka approach may be easiest and the core logic goes along these lines (I can't share the code from work so have just put this together from the examples in the docs, not tested):

```
public Route createRoute(ActorSystem system) {
  return path("ws", () -> {
    ConsumerSettings<byte[], String> consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings.create(system, new ByteArrayDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer())
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
      .withGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) //this is so that each client gets all messages. To be able to resume from where a client left off in case of disconnects, you can generate in on the client side and pass in the request
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")

    return handleWebSocketMessages(
      Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(
        Sink.ignore(),
        Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("topic1"))
          .map(msg -> TextMessage.create(msg.record().value()))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

To expose this route you can follow the [minimalistic example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/index.html#minimal-example), the only difference being the route you define needs the ActorSystem:

```
final Http http = Http.get(system);
final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

final Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed> routeFlow = createRoute(system).flow(system, materializer);
final CompletionStage<ServerBinding> binding = http.bindAndHandle(routeFlow,
    ConnectHttp.toHost("localhost", 8080), materializer);
```

Once you have your messages published to the websocket, the front end will code will of course depend on your UI framework of choice, the simplest code to consume ws messages from javascript is:

```
this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://url-to-your-ws-endpoint');
this.connection.onmessage = evt => { 
  // display the message
```

To easily display the message in the UI, you want the format to be something convenient, like JSON. If your Kafka messages are not JSON already, that's where the Deserializers in the first snippet come in, you can convert it to a convenient JSON string in the Deserializer or do it later on in the .map() called on the Source object.

Alternatively, if polling is an option you can also consider using the off-the-shelf [Kafka Rest Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest), then you only need to build the front-end.